# What is the deal with php pdo's param types?

Tags: php, pdo

Why did the designers of php's PDO objects create types for  `PDO::PARAM_BOOL`, `PDO::PARAM_INT` and `PDO::PARAM_STR` but not for  `PDO::PARAM_DATE`, `PDO::PARAM_TIMESTAMP` or even `PDO::PARAM_DOUBLE`, etc?

Especially curious to me, why did they implement doubles as a string? It's not like doubles are supposed to be quoted.  If there is some reason, why did they decided to treat integers differently than doubles?

My hope is that I'm making some kind of assumption in my expectations that turns out not to be true.  Perhaps the type parameters are only even meant for certain edge cases and mostly I shouldn't worry about them?

Comment: http://php.net/contact.php

Comment: MySQL treats doubles and strings the same? `INSERT INTO aTable (aDouble) VALUES ('100.00')` and `INSERT INTO aTable (aDouble) VALUES (100.00)` are the same?

Beyond that, isn't PDO supposed to be database agnostic?  I'm genuinely curious is there is a real reason for this.

Comment: @hjpotter92 PDO is not just for MySQL

Comment: Ah, damn! I should start experiencing other drivers as well...

Comment: This could have been interesting, unfortunately you don't have a question

Comment: @meda I count three.  If you don't see a question, but it's almost interesting, would you like to suggest an edit?

Comment: @EricG yes it is interesting post because you are pointing out something that should be obvious. It would be great if you reworded to ask a specific question.

Comment: its allmost like having a nice physics questions, then ask why is the sky blue?

Comment: Why does php's PDO have types for  PDO::PARAM_BOOL, PDO::PARAM_INT and PDO::PARAM_STR but not for  PDO::PARAM_DATE, PDO::PARAM_TIMESTAMP or even PDO::PARAM_DOUBLE, etc? I want to know the reason the designers of the language created some pdo types, but not a reasonably complete set.  What's not clear about that?

Comment: And for the record, why is the sky blue is a great physics question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17 which of course clarifies that the sky isn't always blue....

Comment: My random guess would be because PDO *is* database agnostic, and these things can reasonably be different types in various databases, and as such it makes sense to provide native type binding for them. Just because it doesn't do anything special in MySQL doesn't mean it never does.

Comment: Yes, MySQL treats doubles and strings the same in queries.